Netsuite Saved Search Reports
Is there a way using any etl tool (such as IICS,Stitch etc), that we can move netsuite saved search reports to a database. I am aware that a schedule Email  of reports is possible, I am checking if any etl tool can move these reports on an etl to a database

You need to set up a connection to NetSuite in IICS using the NetSuite connector. You’ll need your NetSuite account credentials and access to saved searches. Use the NetSuite connector to fetch data from your saved search, transform it if needed and then load it into the database
